# OpenCV: Grayscale image displayed in greenish color

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am doing my first steps using OpenCV (version 3.3.0 from `opencv-python` package on Mac OS). Using OpenCV inside `jupyter notebook` and displaying a greyscale image through `matplotlib`results in a greenish image instead of a greyscale one.

```
%matplotlib inline

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 8.0)

img = cv.imread('IMG_20171212_222022.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: greenish image from jupyter notebook]

Do you know where this comes from? Is this a bug or desired behavior?

Comment: Seems like you are getting a colormap based on the grayscale values. I'm not familiar with the OpenCV Python interface- but that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: This is not about OpenCV, you're calling [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) from Matplotlib, which uses a colormap when displaying single channel images. Just [pick one](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) that's more appropriate...

Comment: plt.imshow(img, cmap = plt.cm.gray)